# is there a way to see how many times your py or exe file is being ran at that current moment? Python

Tags: python, exe

Is there a way I can see how many times my exe, or py file is running at that current moment, for example :
I double-click on the file "hello.py" twice, meaning the same program is being run twice in the background, how can I check how many times my py or exe file is being run? Or is this something completely undetectable?

Comment: This is not python specific, but OS dependent. I.e. in windows, you could just check the task manager, on unix systems, you can usually use something like `top` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you how to identify which script is being ran, but code below will show you how many python scripts are currently running:

You can then use this to close duplicate procceses for example, or give the user an error saying the script is already running:

```html
import psutil
# Iterate over all running process
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        # Get process name & pid from process object.
        processName = proc.name()
        processID = proc.pid
        if 'python' in processName:
            print(processName , ' ::: ', processID)
    except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
        pass
```

```
Output example: 
python.exe  :::  3756
python.exe  :::  14144
python.exe  :::  16032
python.exe  :::  20124
python.exe  :::  22152
```

resource: https://thispointer.com/python-get-list-of-all-running-processes-and-sort-by-highest-memory-usage/

If you replace the if 'python' statement, you can also get a list of all exe processes running.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a direct methord but what I would do if I were you is :
**I would first create a file named count.py and write a = [0] in it, then would import it and increment its value :**

```
import count

b = count.a[0]
b = b + 1
count.a[0] = b
print(b)
```

But that will only change it in current program so you need to append this change in count.py :

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Yasin\Documents\Aayan\Aayan Programming Projects\Python\count.py", "a") as f:
    f.write(f"a[0]={b}\n")
```

**Conclusion :**

> You are just incrementing the number as you do it in loops, the difference is you are doing it from a file.

**Steps :**

- import file to get number
- Write file to change the number or to add the number with one.

***So every time you run your program it will change the number in count.py and you can identify how many times you ran the file by checking the list in count.py or by printing it : `print(count.a[0])`.***